# how to give an alert when text of input-tag changes

Tags: knockout.js

I wanted to know if it was possible to fire a function which gives an alert of the actual text in the input text.

like for example

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: searchText"/>
```

Now if you write something in the input box a function should be called that fires a message box with the value you wrote into the input box without unfocusing the input box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `valueUpdate` option of the [value binding:](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) where you can specify other events for updating your observable instead of the default change event:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: searchText, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
```

Then you subscribe on your searchText changes

```
this.searchText.subscribe(function(newValue) {
   //Do something when the user types soemthing
});
```

But maybe you will need [throttle extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html) to not fire the event on every keystroke:

```
this.searchText = ko.observable('').extend({ throttle: 500 });
```